# Combinatory Categorial Grammar for inflected languages?

Tags: computational-linguistics, grammar, inflection

Can combinatory categorial grammars be used for inflected languages like Slavic and Baltic languages? I am aware only of this thesis https://pwmarcz.pl/pm-thesis-final.pdf

As far as I have investigated the papers in this field, I can say that there are no wonders: each inflection of each word (verb, subject) is entered as new word in lexicon.